# IEEEtran - Whitespace before first author

Tags: horizontal-alignment, indentation, ieeetran, white-space

How do I remove a whitespace which is before the first author of my authorblock? I thought it was some kind of indentation, but I haven't managed to remove it.
Here is the code I'm using:

```
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
% The preceding line is only needed to identify funding in the first footnote. If that is unneeded, please comment it out.
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
\renewcommand*{\thesubsection}{\Alph{subsection}}
\renewcommand*{\thesubsubsection}{\roman{subsubsection}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\newlineauthors}{%
  \end{@IEEEauthorhalign}\hfill\mbox{}\par
  \mbox{}\hfill\begin{@IEEEauthorhalign}
}
\makeatother

\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
    
\begin{document}

\title{Comparación de la efectividad de algoritmos de corrección de color en imágenes capturadas por la cámara Samsung wb1100f bajo diferentes tipos de iluminación\\}



\author{
\IEEEauthorblockN{Gudiño Pacha, Paul Mauricio }
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{Facultad de Ingeniería en Electricidad y Computación}\\
\textit{Escuela Superior Politécnica del Litoral}\\
Guayaquil, Ecuador \\
pgudino@espol.edu.ec\\}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{Intriago Sánchez, Noelia Alejandra}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{Facultad de Ingeniería en Electricidad y Computación}\\
\textit{Escuela Superior Politécnica del Litoral}\\
Guayaquil, Ecuador \\
noinsanc@espol.edu.ec\\}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{Ramos Mendoza, Hans Petter}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{Facultad de Ingeniería en Electricidad y Computación}\\
\textit{Escuela Superior Politécnica del Litoral}\\
Guayaquil, Ecuador \\
hanpramo@espol.edu.ec\\}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{Vulgarín Punguil, Jorge Adrián}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{Facultad de Ingeniería en Electricidad y Computación}\\
\textit{Escuela Superior Politécnica del Litoral}\\
Guayaquil, Ecuador \\
jvulgari@espol.edu.ec\\}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{Ochoa Donoso, Daniel Erick}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{Facultad de Ingeniería en Electricidad y Computación}\\
\textit{Escuela Superior Politécnica del Litoral}\\
Guayaquil, Ecuador \\
dochoa@espol.edu.ec\\}
}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image: There's the whitespace]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Your code isn't compilable since it's missing the `\documentclass` directive. Please fix.

Comment: @Mico already fixed :) my bad

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read the example in `bare_conf.tex`.

[image]

```latex
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\author{%
\IEEEauthorblockN{%
Gudiño Pacha, Paul Mauricio\IEEEauthorrefmark{1},
Intriago Sánchez, Noelia Alejandra\IEEEauthorrefmark{1},
Ramos Mendoza, Hans Petter\IEEEauthorrefmark{1},\\
Vulgarín Punguil, Jorge Adrián\IEEEauthorrefmark{1} and
Ochoa Donoso, Daniel Erick\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}%
}%
\IEEEauthorblockA{%
\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}%
\textit{Facultad de Ingeniería en Electricidad y Computación}\\%
\textit{Escuela Superior Politécnica del Litoral}\\%
Guayaquil, Ecuador\\%
Email: \{pgudino, noinsanc, hanpramo, jvulgari, dochoa\}@espol.edu.ec}%
}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]